# How does this cyclic recursion provide the desired result?

Tags: haskell, recursion, random

Consider the following abbreviated code from [this excellent blog post](http://blog.functorial.com/posts/2012-08-04-Testing-Random-Properties-With-Type-Classes.html):

```
import System.Random (Random, randomRIO)

newtype Stream m a = Stream { runStream :: m (Maybe (NonEmptyStream m a)) }
type NonEmptyStream m a = (a, Stream m a)

empty :: (Monad m) => Stream m a
empty = Stream $ return Nothing

cons :: (Monad m) => a -> Stream m a -> Stream m a
cons a s = Stream $ return (Just (a, s))

fromList :: (Monad m) => [a] -> NonEmptyStream m a
fromList (x:xs) = (x, foldr cons empty xs)
```

Not too bad thus far - a monadic, recursive data structure and a way to build one from a list.

Now consider this function that chooses a (uniformly) random element from a stream, using constant memory:

```
select :: NonEmptyStream IO a -> IO a
select (a, s) = select' (return a) 1 s where
  select' :: IO a -> Int -> Stream IO a -> IO a
  select' a n s = do
    next <- runStream s
    case next of 
      Nothing -> a
      Just (a', s') -> select' someA (n + 1) s' where
        someA = do i <- randomRIO (0, n) 
                   case i of 0 -> return a'
                             _ -> a
```

I'm not grasping the mysterious cyclic well of infinity that's going on in the last four lines; the result `a'` depends on a recursion on `someA`, which itself *could* depend on `a'`, but not necessarily.

I get the vibe that the recursive worker is somehow 'accumulating' potential values in the `IO a` accumulator, but I obviously can't reason about it well enough.

Could anyone provide an explanation as to how this function produces the behaviour that it does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code doesn't actually run in constant space, as it composes a bigger and bigger `IO a` action which delays all the random choices until it's reached the end of the stream. Only when we reach the `Nothing -> a` case does the action in `a` actually get run.

For example, try running it on an infinite, constant space stream made by this function:

```
repeat' :: a -> NonEmptyStream IO a
repeat' x = let xs = (x, Stream $ return (Just xs)) in xs
```

Obviously, running `select` on this stream won't terminate, but you should see the memory usage going up as it allocates a lot of thunks for the delayed actions.

Here's a slightly re-written version of the code which does the choices as it goes along, so it runs in constant space and should hopefully be more clear as well. Note that I've replaced the `IO a` argument with a plain `a` which makes it clear that there are no delayed actions being built up here.

```
select :: NonEmptyStream IO a -> IO a
select (x, xs) = select' x 1 xs where
  select' :: a -> Int -> Stream IO a -> IO a
  select' current n xs = do
    next <- runStream xs
    case next of 
      Nothing       -> return current
      Just (x, xs') -> do
        i <- randomRIO (0, n)                         -- (1)
        case i of                                     
          0 -> select' x       (n+1) xs'              -- (2)
          _ -> select' current (n+1) xs'              -- (3)
```

As the name implies, `current` stores the currently selected value at each step. Once we've extracted the next item from the stream, we (1) pick a random number and use this to decide whether to (2) replace our selection with the new item or (3) keep our current selection before recursing on the rest of the stream.

Comment: shouldn't the last two recursive calls use `xs'` instead of `xs`?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem anything "cyclic" going on here. In particular, `a'` does *not* depend on `someA`. The `a'` is bound by pattern machting on the result of `next`. It is being used by `someA` which is in turn used on the right hand side, but this does not constitute a cycle.

What `select'` does is to traverse the stream. It maintains two accumulating arguments. The first is a random element from the stream (it's not yet selected and still random, hence `IO a`). The second is the position in the stream (`Int`).

The invariant being maintained is that the first accumulator selects an element uniformly from the stream we have seen so far, and that the integer represents the number of elements encountered so far.

Now, if we reach the end of the stream (`Nothing`), we can return the current random element, and it will be ok.

If we see another element (the `Just` case), then we recurse by calling `select'` again. Updating the number of elements to `n + 1` is trivial. But how do we update the random element `someA`? Well, the old random element `a` chooses between the first `n` positions of the stream with equal probability. If we choose the new element `a'` with probability `1 / (n + 1)` and use the old one in all other cases, then we have a uniform distribution over the whole stream up to this point again.